# Load local json file to ajax

Tags: php, json, jquery

I have a local json file which is needed to be populated in the my view, in label
Code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready($.getJSON("js/records.json", function(data){
            $.ajax({           
                //data format      
                success: function(data){    //on recieve of reply
                    $("#cat").append('<option selected>category</option>');
                    for(i in data) 
                        $("#cat").append('<option value="'+data[i].q_title+'">'+data[i].q_title+'</option>');
                } 

            });
```

Comment: This isn't a question.

Comment: And your problem/error is…?

Comment: Good. Its a very good thing that you want to populate in the view.

Comment: `$(document).ready($.getJSON(...))` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Why are you calling `$.ajax` inside the callback for `$.getJSON`?  What the heck are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont get why you are doing an AJAX request inside an AJAX request. But the code may look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: "js/records.json",
dataType: "json",
mimeType: "textPlain"
})          
.done(function(data){
  //Insert code here
});
```

Also if you are using chrome (didn't test on other browser) you will get problems requesting JSON locally. Try it out on a webserver or else look for the error in your console log and fix it yourself.

Comment: sorry guys, I just looked at what I wrote "face palm" . dead line give u stress, I figured it out. thank you